# Need help using acts_as_rateable with jquery star rating

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rating

I'm really messed up with javascript, is anyone willing to walk me through setting up a star rating with acts_as_rateable plugin and either http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/ or http://rateit.codeplex.com/

I've already got acts_as_rateable set up and working fine. I was following this http://miguelsanmiguel.com/2010/11/28/star-rating-for-rails-3-and-jquery but I hit a wall maybe with jquery 1.6 or something else I can't figure it out.

I believe I need a form_for, a helper and maybe some js code somewhere??

I will need to display multiple ratings on the same page for various items, but only one main item will be rateable.

Answer (score 0):

For the item that you want users to be able to give a rating, you need a form which posts the rating to the corresponding model.

[This rubydoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/kamui/ajaxful_rating_jquery/master/frames) is an instant unobtrusive AJAX solution for rails 2.3

[Episode 101 on Refactoring Out Helper Objects](http://railscasts.com/episodes/101-refactoring-out-helper-object) might be helpful to watch,
it may be a bit dated since its posted in 2008 but Ryan is good at explaining things

Comment: Yes it's RoR 2.3, that is why I mentioned it.
The github page does contain a [rails3 branch](https://github.com/kamui/ajaxful_rating_jquery/tree/rails3)

Comment: I tried out the ajaxful_rating and i get this error. RJS error: 
TypeError: Object function Element() { [native code] } has no method 'update'  Any help?

Comment: I'm sorry, my JavaScript knowledge is limited. I would not know how to answer unless I really dig into the problem. Unfortunately, I don't have that kind of time.

Comment: Maybe you could add the Jquery tag as well? It might get more views that way. Someone is bound to know the complete answer to this